# How to use Order by Query in Google Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

How can I use a Order-By Query for a fusion table Layer.

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'LATITUDE',
            from: '0ILwUgu7vj0VSZnVzaW9udGFibGVzOjEzNjcwNQ'
            //order-by : index,
            //group-by : group
          },
          map: map
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation for FusionTablesQuery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesQuery)

> Properties
> from | Type:string | The ID of the Fusion Tables table to display. This ID can be found in the table's URL, as the value of the dsrcid parameter. Required.
>
> limit | Type:number | Limit on the number of results returned by the query.
>
> offset | Type:number | Offset into the sorted results.
>
> **orderBy** | Type:string | The method by which to sort the results. Accepts either of:
>
> - A column name. The column name may be suffixed with ASC or DESC (e.g. col2 DESC) to specify ascending or descending sort.
> - An ST_DISTANCE spatial relationship (sort by distance). A column and the coordinate from which to calculate distance must be passed, for example, orderBy: 'ST_DISTANCE(col1, LATLNG(1.2, 3.4))'.
>
> select | Type:string | A column, containing geographic features to be displayed on the map. See Fusion Tables Setup in the Maps API documentation for information about valid columns.
>
> where | Type:string | The SQL predicate to be applied to the layer.

There is no order-by or group-by.  You may be able to include the "group" in the where clause.